# Documentation for spark options

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

This one is probably easy to answer, but for the life of me I can't seem to find this.

Can someone please point me to documentation for the various key-value pair options that you can use with spark?

Example of such an option (in pyspark):

```
some_spark_table.write.format("parquet").option("parquet.block.size", 1234)
```

So if I'm interested in what the unit is for the `parquet.block.size` option, where do I find that?

I found [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#manually-specifying-options) which helpfully states: "To find more detailed information about the extra ORC/Parquet options, visit the official Apache ORC/Parquet websites." But I still can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As doc says, you can visit the official Apache Parquet website. I think by official website they mean [Parquet git repo](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-hadoop) :)

Citing from there:

> **Property:** parquet.block.size
>  
>   **Description:** The block size in bytes. This property depends on the file system:
>
> - If the file system (FS) used supports blocks like HDFS, the block size
>     will be the maximum between the default block size of FS and this
>     property. And the row group size will be equal to this property.
>
>   - `block_size = max(default_fs_block_size, parquet.block.size)`
>   - `row_group_size = parquet.block.size`
> - If the file system used doesn't support blocks, then this property will define the row group size.
>
> Note that larger values of row group size will improve the IO when
>   reading but consume more memory when writing
>  
>   **Default value:** 134217728 (128 MB)

Unlike Parquet, Spark's own configuration settings are pretty well documented (the ones they want you to know about) on its website as pointed in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go through the official documentation to find the properties.
For example, properties related to parquet
(https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#configuration)

While most of the configuration related properties you can find [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did find those links, however, none of them mentions the options that I want to look at (e.g. block size for parquet files)...

Comment: Yeah, I don't see it either